# reset form after settimeout

Tags: jquery, forms, settimeout, reset

I want to reset a form after setTimeout function call, somehow my syntax is not working correctly

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#alert-success').slideUp('slow', resetForm('crt_clt'));
}, 5000);
</script>​​
```

Please correct my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should properly use the *complete* callback function of [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/):

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $("#alert-success").slideUp("slow", function() {
       resetForm("crt_clt");
   });
}, 5000);
```